# How to Get the iteration path or iteration ID in TFS rest API?

Tags: tfs, wiql

I'm trying to get the tasks of a specific iteration. I know I can get that with the iteration path or the Iteration ID. I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM WorkItems
  WHERE [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'
    AND [System.IterationID] = 24138
```

The query works fine, but I don't have a way to get that Iteration path or the Iteration ID.

Is there a way to get the iteration ID?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to query the tables from Tfs_Warehouse database. You can find the reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244691.aspx). The query looks like below:

```
SELECT * from DimWorkItem dwi
INNER JOIN DimIteration di on dwi.IterationSK=di.IterationSK
WHERE dwi.System_WorkItemType = 'Task'
AND di.IterationPath = 'foobar'
```

Comment: It is posible to make queries to the TFS_Warehouse with the REST API?